# How can I import classes from import *, not modules

Tags: python

I have a folder structure as below

```
\root
   |-collections
     |-__init__.py
     |-collection1.py   => contains Collection1 class
     |-collection2.py   => contains Collection2 class
     |-...so on
   |-db.py
```

Inside of db.py, I need to use all of the Collection<n> classes. Is there any way to import them like the code below? Apparently __all__ variable in __init__.py only allows module names, not classes.

```
# db.py
from root.collections import *

a = Collection1()
b = Collection2()
...
```

Here's my trial and error

```
# collections\__init__.py
from collection1 import Collection1
from collection2 import Collection2
from collection3 import Collection3

__all__ = ['Collection1', 'Collection2', 'Collection3']
```

```
# db.py
def test_collections():
   from root.collections import *
   
   a = Collection1()

test_collections()
```

And this gives me...

```
SyntaxError: import * only allowed at module level
```

Comment: Who told you `__all__` couldn't include class names? The only important limitation is that those classes need to actually be present in (or imported into) your `__init__.py`, so you should be showing that file in your question

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for the comment! I just edited to show the error message. db.py is actually a simplified version of the original.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I see. sorry for my short English. import * should be outside of the method. but another error has just appeared. It says no module named 'collection1' in collections/__init__.py

Comment: @CharlesDuffy ah, just solved the problem. the module name needs to be in the form either of absolute path or relative path. It worked after I put dot(.) in front of each module name. Thank you again.

Comment: Note that solutions should not be in the question itself -- when you do that it privileges one answer over all others, and makes other peoples' answers no longer make sense. Use the "Add an Answer" button even for an answer you write yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import the classes in `__init__.py`:

```
__all__ = ['Collection1', 'Collection2']

from .collection1 import Collection1
from .collection2 import Collection2
```